Multithreaded program with UDP protocol doesn't work on ESP32
I'm learning to work with MQTT server and client and UDP protocol with ESP32.
I have a problem with ESP32 rebooting every second when there are two threads in code: one for sending and one for receiving UDP datagrams. Could anyone help me with this issue, please?
There is my code
#include <WiFi.h>
    #include "AsyncUDP.h"
    #include <MQTT.h>
    #include <WiFiUdp.h>
    #include <OSCMessage.h>

    TaskHandle_t thread;
    
    WiFiClient net;
    const char* ssid = "---"; //some info
    const char* password = "---"; //some info
    
    IPAddress outIp(***, ***, ***, ***); //some info
    const unsigned int outPort = ----; //some info
    
    MQTTClient mqttClient;
    int port = ----; //some info
    long lastMillis = 0;
    String ping = "";
    String address = "";
    bool start = true;
    
    AsyncUDP udp;
    AsyncUDP udpThread;
    AsyncUDPMessage udpMsg;
    
    uint32_t timeConnect;
    uint32_t timeOffset;
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
    
      xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
        threadLoop, 
        "Thread",   
        10000,      
        NULL,      
        1,          
        &thread,    
        0);         
    
    
      ConnectToWifi(ssid, password, true);
      Serial.println("Connected to the Wi-Fi network");
    
      ping = GetPing();
      Serial.println(ping);
    }
    
    void loop() {
      OSCMessage msg("/ping");
      msg.add("Some message");
      msg.send(udpMsg);
      msg.empty();
      udp.sendTo(udpMsg, outIp, outPort);
      delay(1000);
    }
    
    void threadLoop(void* pvParameters) {
    
      if (udpThread.listen(port)) {
        String data[2];
        udpThread.onPacket([](AsyncUDPPacket packet) {
          //parse packet
        }
    
        if (data[0] == "***") {
          address = packet.remoteIP().toString(); 
          int addressLen = address.length() + 1;
    
          char broker[addressLen];
          address.toCharArray(broker, addressLen);
    
          mqttClient.begin(broker, net);
          mqttClient.onMessage(Received); //event subscription
    
          char* timeEnd;
          timeConnect = strtol(data[1].c_str(), &timeEnd, 0);
          timeOffset = millis() / 1000ul;
    
          start = true;
        }
      });
    
      while (1) {
        if (start) {
          mqttClient.loop();
          delay(10);
          if (!mqttClient.connected()) {
            ConnectedMQTT();
          }
          if (millis() - lastMillis > 1000) {
            lastMillis = millis();
    
            uint32_t sec = millis() / 1000ul;
            uint32_t time = timeConnect + (sec - timeOffset);
            mqttClient.publish(ping, String(time), true, 0);
          }
        } 
        else {
          udpThread.broadcastTo("***", port);
          delay(1000);
        }
      }
    }

If I replace this part of the code:
      if (udpThread.listen(port)) {
        String data[2];
        udpThread.onPacket(\[\](AsyncUDPPacket packet) {
          //parse packet
      }
    
      if (data[0] == "***") {
        address = packet.remoteIP().toString(); 
        int addressLen = address.length() + 1;
    
        char broker[addressLen];
        address.toCharArray(broker, addressLen);
    
        mqttClient.begin(broker, net);
        mqttClient.onMessage(Received); //event subscription
    
        char* timeEnd;
        timeConnect = strtol(data[1].c_str(), &timeEnd, 0);
        timeOffset = millis() / 1000ul;
    
        start = true;
      }
    });

with this:
    char broker[] = "***, ***, ***, ***"; //some info
    mqttClient.begin(broker, net);
    mqttClient.onMessage(Received); //event subscription

then the ESP32 stops rebooting.
Also, the ESP32 stops rebooting when I leave only loop method:
    void loop() {       
      OSCMessage msg("/ping");       
      msg.add("Some message");       
      msg.send(udpMsg);      
      msg.empty();      
      udp.sendTo(udpMsg, outIp, outPort);   
      delay(1000);
    }


Does your code compile at all? Your udpThread.onPacket([](AsyncUDPPacket packet) {} }); has an extra } if this is your real code.

Please turn on esp exception decoder or use this online esp exception decoder and paste reset output of serial monitor here

Yes, it compiles, may be I forgot to remove extra '}'
